# Reactive forms apply formControlName for a tag instead of a input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form `myForm`

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
```

it has a sub `FormArray` called `emails` within the `myForm`

```
<div formArrayName="emails">
  <div *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('emails')['controls']; let i= index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <input type="text" formControlName="from"/>
```

My question is as `formControlName="from"` is perfectly works, why there is no facility to render like this?

```
<div formArrayName="emails">
  <div *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('emails')['controls']; let i= index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <div> {{from}} </div>
```

why should we write additional code as part of the rendering?

Comment: First of all, I don't see the `from` control is declared in your control, so not sure what it is. Secondary, when working with form, we will take some inputs from users to send it back to the server to process the inputs. Using a div is alright, it just doesn't make sense to use a div as a formControl as we don't use div tag to send input to server. We actually can bind formControl to a div or even a component but that's customization. Angular provides the basic use cases, which is input/textarea/checkbox... If you want customization, you can look for ControlValueAccessor

Comment: so, simply to display a whatsapp message I need to put a border less `<input>` tag to display the message components, which seems little bit odd, why could not angular provide simple facility to display current context values based on `formArrayName` is the array context and `formGroupName` is the index of the array